# Which layout to use for a home replacement application/grid of views?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a home replacement application and I want to know my options, I could use a TableLayout or nested LinearLayouts but the icon size and number of rows and columns of icons can change so I'm looking for something easier to manage, maybe just one layout and have items accomodate automatically somehow.

In HTML div you can use float:left and if you append items on a container they accomodate like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do something similar in Java? If not what is the recommended way to create a grid layout?

Comment: Have you tried.... GridView......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a set of `<LinearViews>` and appending buttons directly on them, I think it's the easiest method if the number of rowsXcols can vary.

```
    for(int c = 0; c < appCols; c++) { // Go through cols
        LinearLayout col = new LinearLayout(context);
        col.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        for(int r = 0; r < appRows; r++) { // Go through rows
            Button button = new Button(context);button.setText(allApps.get(n).activityInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
            button.setWidth(iconWidth);
            button.setHeight(iconHeight);
            // add app icon
            col.addView(button);
            n++;
        }
        // Add column
        layout.addView(col);
    }
```